# Angular 2 how inject dynamically #x template reference variable

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it posible change the reference variable **#x** or **ref-x** dynamically in template and put any name.

Example

```
<modal #x modalClass="modal-lg modal-md any-other-css-class" (onClose)="close();">
```

change it and not put it static in the modal tag.